# CMake simple MVC structure

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, cmake

I have a simple question about how to organize my simple MVC application in C++. I'm new to CMake and I'm just learning how to use it.

Imagine a simple folder organization like the following:

[image: Folder Structure]

-Can someone please tell me if this structure is correct? 
-If so what is the best way to write the cmake files for it?

Comment: Well, if _you_ like the structure, then cmake can deal with it. But I'd consider it too complex. Hint: there can be more then one artifact described in one CMakeLists.txt, so if your MVC components are small enough (in terms of number of files) then you can stay with a single CMakeLists.txt. In any case the structure can be easily changed in a future when number of files changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Would you please give me an example of how CMake can deal with it? And as my project will grow (as I develop it) I would like to have the proper CMakeLists set initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks pretty normal structure to me. In fact I use the same one in my projects.
In the root CMake file you will put:
`include(Src/Model/CMakelists.txt)`
and `CMakelists.txt` might look like this:

```
set(MODEL_HEADERS 
    src/Model/model.hpp)
set(MODEL_SOURCES
    src/Model/model.cpp 
    ${MODEL_HEADERS})
list(APPEND ALL_SOURCES ${MODEL_SOURCES})
source_group("Model" FILES ${MODEL_SOURCES})
```

Where `ALL_SOURCES` is the variable from the root file which is later passed to `add_executable`

Repeat the same for all your subfolders and you will have the final project.

Comment: Thanks so much @ixSci. only few questions:
I'm right now using this:
`file (GLOB MY_SRCS *.cpp)` in my root folder. What's the difference between saying **file** and **set** in usage?
I guess you meant to use `set(<var> <vale>)` in the root **CMakelists.txt** to defined the **ALL_SOURCES** right?
My apologies if I'm asking something that has been already answered I'm new to CMake and try to read the documentations as well sometimes I get confused and need help.

Comment: @Ash, `set` is used to set a variable to some value. `file` is a function which manipulates files. In your case you get all cpp files by using that function. Yes I always use `set` I never use `file` for building the list of the sources.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for so many edits :) it's my third time I'm using stackoverflow :P so to take care of main.cpp you suggest I use set in the root CMakelists.txt as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a usual way of using CMake - use `set` to build the list of your sources.

Comment: @Ash, btw, if it answers your question, please tick the mark besides the answer to accept it.

Comment: sure I'll try it out and will get back here. I know how stackoverflow works :)

Comment: I can't get visual studio include my header files in the project @ixSci. **I moved the main to src folder** and now here what I have for the code:
`project (test)
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.9 )
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -g")

set (MAIN_SRC "main.cpp" ${MAIN_SRC})
list(APPEND ALL_SRCS ${MAIN_SRC})

add_subdirectory (controller)
#add_subdirectory (model)
#add_subdirectory (view)

add_executable (test ${ALL_SRCS})`

Comment: and here is the subfolder:
`#SUB_FOLDER
set (CTRL_HDRS controller/controller.hpp)
set (CTRL_SRCS controller/controller.cpp ${CTRL_HDRS})
list (APPEND ALL_SRCS ${CTRL_SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)
source_group ("Controller" FILES ${CTRL_SRCS})`

Comment: @Ash, if you looked at my answer you would see your errors immediately. I will reiterate, though. First replace `set (MAIN_SRC "main.cpp" ${MAIN_SRC})` with `set (MAIN_SRC main.cpp)` then `add_subdirectory (controller)` with `include(controllerl/CMakelists.txt)` and `list (APPEND ALL_SRCS ${CTRL_SRCS} PARENT_SCOPE)` with `list (APPEND ALL_SRCS ${CTRL_SRCS})`